# Using a plugin system with C++ object and standard library containers

Tags: c++, dll, abi

After reading a lot about using plugins which means using C++ objects in dynamically loaded shared libraries the outcome was mostly: Do not.

1. Especially do not use standard library containers or templates at all.
2. When you try plugins with C++ you must use the same compiler with the same flags and the same standard library. Even then there might be crashes.

I made a simple class loader myself which works fine using the same compiler and the plugins actually compile in the same project. What I do is registering factory functions for my classes which can be called. This works quite well and other libraries like Poco C++ does the same.

I'm interested how you people solve the problem with ABI compatibility over library boundaries. Some of you might say, don't use plugins at all or stick to pure C functions and types. I do that wherever possible but it is C++ and the reason for using C++ is because it solves some Problems which are not feasible in pure C.

I know that there possibly never will be a standard C++ ABI for good reasons so I'm really interested how you avoid problems when using standard library and C++ plugins.

Comment: There are only two ways, and you've already listed them.  (1) choose a stable, well defined ABI (like C or COM), or (2) ensure that all your binaries are built as a unit using the same set of tools.

Comment: "Problems which are feasible in pure C." -> "Problems which are not feasible in pure C." ?

Comment: Thanks I fixed that

Answer (score 1):

"I'm interested how you people solve the problem with ABI compatibility over library boundaries" - We make sure to build all the dependencies/libraries as well as the executable from scratch, every time, with the exact same compiler.   At least, that's what *I* do.